# Creating an Excel Sheet with ADO.NET (OleDb) --> What DataTypes are Supported?

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net, oledb

I try to create an Excel (2003) Sheet with ADO.NET (OleDb).

I was able to create the Sheet with an OleDbCommand:

```
var cnnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;...";
var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnString);
var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
cnn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MySheet (ID char(255), Field1 char(255))";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That works as expected.

Here my Question:
What DataTypes (like char(255)) are Supported by Excel within the CREATE TABLE command? I did google but didn't find any documentation or hints.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excel recognizes only a limited set of [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687869.aspx).  For example:

- All numeric columns are doubles
- All string columns (other than memo columns) are 255-character Unicode strings

**Numbers**

**All versions of Excel:**

- 8-byte double
- [signed] short [int] – used for Boolean values and also integers
- unsigned short [int]
- [signed long] int

**Strings**

**All versions of Excel:**

- [signed] char * – null-terminated byte strings of up to 255 characters
- unsigned char * – length-counted byte strings of up to 255 characters

**Excel 2007+ only:**

- unsigned short * – Unicode strings of up to 32,767 characters, which can be null-terminated or length-counted

Answer (score 0):

You will always get better results using the Excel object model directly, and there isn't much more code required. See [example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529703/how-to-create-a-excel-file-with-sheets-in-c)

or if you wanted to get really keen you could try the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office

Comment: I can't use the object model, because i have to create the excel on a server.

Comment: Have a look at the Open XML SDK 2.0 then. Still a much more efficient and precise way of generating .xlsx. If you need .xls you might be better off with some third party components?

Comment: There is an update for Office 2003 to r/w .xslx docs etc. IIRC it's called "2003 Compatibility FileFormatConverters"